# Showing $B_P$ is a finitely generated module over $A_P$ where $P$ is a prime ideal in a Dedekind domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

Suppose we have $A$ a Dedekind domain, $K$ its field of fractions. Let $L$ be a field extension of $K$ of degree $n$ and also that it is separable. 
Let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $L$.

> Let $P$ be a prime ideal in $A$. I am having trouble seeing why $B_P := (A \backslash P)^{-1} B$ is a finitely generated $A_P$-module.

This was skipped in a lecture and I was trying to figure out, but I am not quite seeing it at the moment. I would greatly appreciate any hints/answers! Thanks!

Comment: PS I am assuming I have to use separability, which implies it is a simple extension, to make a spanning set...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

This is because separability implies $B$ itself is a finitely generated $A$-module. Furthermore, it is unrelated to $A$ being a Dedekind domain: it is enough that $A$ be noetherian and integrally closed.

Comment: Could you possibly give me another hint on how to show that $B$ is a finitely generated $A$ module? I think this is where I am getting stuck...

Comment: The proof that is usually given in textbooks is nonintuitive if you haven't seen it before.  It relies on the fact that the trace map in separable extensions is never the zero map, and the existence of a "dual basis" with respect to the trace.

Answer (score 1):

Proof in several steps.  You are probably familiar with many of the steps, but for the sake of a complete argument here is some overkill:

> 1 .  Let $v_1, ... , v_n$ be a basis for $L/K$.  Show that there exists a basis $w_1, ... , w_n$ for $L/K$ such that $Tr(v_iw_j) = \delta_{ij}$, where $Tr$ is the trace map $L \rightarrow K$.

Hint: consider $L$ as a vector space over $K$.  Define a function $B: L \times L \rightarrow K$ by $B(x,y) = Tr(xy)$.  Let $L^{\ast}$ be the *dual* of $L$ as a vector space over $K$, i.e. $L = \textrm{Hom}_K(L,K)$.  Show that there is an isomorphism $\Phi: L \rightarrow L^{\ast}$ defined by basis elements by $\Phi(v_i) = B(v_i,-)$.

Recall from linear algebra that there is a basis $v_1^{\ast}, ... , v_n^{\ast}$ of $L^{\ast}$, where $v_i^{\ast}$ is the function from $L$ to $K$ defined by $v_i^{\ast}(c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_nv_n) = c_i$.  You can then define $w_i$ to be $\Phi^{-1}(v_i^{\ast})$, and show it has the required property.

> 2 .  To show that $B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module (from which it follows that $B_P$ is finitely generated over $A_P$), show that this is done if we have shown that $B$ is *contained* in a finitely generated $A$-module.

Hint: a module $M$ over a given ring (Noetherian or not) is called Noetherian if every ascending chain of submodules terminates, or equivalently every submodule of $M$ is finitely generated.  Quotients and submodules of Noetherian modules are Noetherian; conversely if $N$ is a submodule of $M$ and $N$ and $M/N$ are both Noetherian, then so is $M$.  If $A$ is a Noetherian ring, show that $A^k = \bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^k A$ is a Noetherian $A$-module. A finitely generated module over $A$ is the same thing as a quotient $A^k/N$ for some $k$ and some submodule $N$ of $A^k$.  Hence a finitely generated module over $A$ is Noetherian.  Thus any submodule of a finitely generated $A$-module is itself finitely generated.

> 3 .  Show that there exists a basis $v_1, ... , v_n$ for $L/K$ such that the $v_i$ are integral over $A$, i.e. $v_i \in B$.

Hint: $x \in L$ is integral over $A$ if and only if its monic minimal polynomial has coefficients in $A$.

> 4 .  Assume $v_i$ is a basis for $L/K$ with $v_i \in B$.  Let $w_1, ... , w_n$ be the dual basis from (1).  Show that there exists a $c \in A$ such that $cw_i$ are integral over $A$.

(same as (3)).

> 5 .  If $x \in B$, show that $Tr(x) \in A$.

The coefficients of the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $K$ lie in $A$.

> 6 .  Show that $B \subseteq Ac^{-1}v_1 + \cdots + Ac^{-1}v_n$.

If $z \in B$, write $z = c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_nv_n$ for $c_i \in K$.  If you can show that $cc_i \in A$ for all $i$, then you are done.  To do this, multiply both sides by $cw_i$ and take the trace.  Use the fact that $Tr(B) \subseteq A$.